# Apache ranger 2.1.0 - Installation failed

Tags: apache-ranger

I am trying to install the latest version of Apache ranger 2.1.0 and getting this error while installing ranger admin. `[E] Ranger all admins default password change request failed` and there is not much error logs.

```
2020-09-05 20:21:14,541  [JISQL] /usr/lib/jvm/jre-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-0.el7_8.x86_64/bin/java  -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/opt/apache-ranger/ranger-2.1.0-admin/jisql/lib/* org.apache.util.sql.Jisql -driver mysqlconj -cstring jdbc:mysql://localhost/ranger -u 'ranger' -p '********' -noheader -trim -c \;  -query "insert into x_db_version_h (version, inst_at, inst_by, updated_at, updated_by,active) values ('DEFAULT_ALL_ADMIN_UPDATE', current_timestamp, 'Ranger 2.1.0', current_timestamp, 'pas-bifrostx0.myntra.com','N') ;"
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-09-05 20:21:15,219  [I] Ranger all admins default password change request is in process..
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper (file:/opt/apache-ranger/ranger-2.1.0-admin/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/eclipselink-2.5.2.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getXmlEncoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-09-05 20:21:19,448  [JISQL] /usr/lib/jvm/jre-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-0.el7_8.x86_64/bin/java  -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/opt/apache-ranger/ranger-2.1.0-admin/jisql/lib/* org.apache.util.sql.Jisql -driver mysqlconj -cstring jdbc:mysql://localhost/ranger -u 'ranger' -p '********' -noheader -trim -c \;  -query "delete from x_db_version_h where version = 'DEFAULT_ALL_ADMIN_UPDATE' and active = 'N' and updated_by='pas-bifrostx0.myntra.com';"
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-09-05 20:21:20,073  [E] Ranger all admins default password change request failed
```

Also, regardless of this error, I was able to start the service with `sudo ranger-admin start` and is able to do `telnet localhost 6080` but web UI is not showing up.

Found the following error in `ews/logs/catalina.out`

```
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class org.apache.ranger.entity.XXAccessAuditV4] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [defaultPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class org.apache.ranger.entity.XXAccessAuditV4] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [defaultPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class org.apache.ranger.entity.XXAccessAuditV4] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class org.apache.ranger.entity.XXAccessAuditV4] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.noPrimaryKeyAnnotationsFound(ValidationException.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.validatePrimaryKey(EntityAccessor.java:1536)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1793)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
    ... 28 more

Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.DriverImpl] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2dfce76e]) and a value of type [org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.Statistics.StatisticsData] (value [9910 bytes read, 0 bytes written, 0 read ops, 0 large read ops, 0 write ops]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer.ThreadLocalContext] (value [org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$ThreadLocalContext@4073a8a9]) and a value of type [org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer.ThreadContext] (value [org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$ThreadContext@42aecda1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-6080"]
Sep 05, 2020 2:56:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase findResourceInternal
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
```

Can someone please help here or redirect me to Ranger community so that I can reach out to someone for here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issues were related to JAVA 11. I was trying to run ranger with JAVA 11
(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RANGER-2575) but seems like it doesn't work. Building and running against java 8 worked.